# if folder exists with PHP

Tags: php

I'd love some help....i'm not sure where to start in creating a script that searches for a folder in a directory and if it doesnt exist then it will simply move up one level (not keep going up till it finds one)

I am using this code to get a list of images.  But if this folder didn't exist i would want it to move up to its parent.

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator("/home/domain.co.uk/public_html/assets/images/bg-images/{last_segment}"); foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile() && !preg_match('/-c\.jpg$/', $fileinfo->getFilename())) {
        $bgimagearray[] = "'" . $fileinfo->getFilename() . "'";
    } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your directory name in a variable.

```
$directory = "/home/domain.co.uk/public_html/assets/images/bg-images/{last_segment}";

// if directory does not exist, set it to directory above.
if(!is_dir($directory)){
  $directory = dirname($directory)  
}

$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
```

Comment: `$directory = dirname($directory)` will do 1-level trimming elegantly

Comment: @Andy - Use the ! operator when you want something to happen if a condition is _not_ met.  Using ! allowed for a very easy solution indeed.  Happy coding friend.

Comment: Would it be possible do you think to go up more levels until it finds a directory...but with a value that stops it if it matches?

Answer (score 2):

It works: `file_exists($pathToDir)`

Answer (score 1):

To test if a directory exists, use is_dir()

http://php.net/function.is-dir

To move up to the parent directory would be by chdir('..');

http://php.net/function.chdir